# How can I disable auto fill in SAP 770?

Tags: sap

Specifically T-code MB51, once I have finished looking at transactions specific to a material number and go back to the initial MB51 to input a new material, I find that a document number from the previous material has auto populated as well as the date of the last transaction I looked at. I have tried going into the options on the log on window and turning off enhanced search as well as the history.

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented via SPA/GPA parameters and is intended for values [auto-fill](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-US/4a/43a3d65a503f04e10000000a421937/content.htm?no_cache=true).

And unfortunately there is no way to disable it.